# `INTERSECT` vs `INNER JOIN` in PDO SQLite

Tags: performance, sqlite

I wonder which way is faster

```
SELECT Id FROM T1
INTERSECT
SELECT Id FROM T2
```

or

```
SELECT T1.Id
    FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id
```

Comment: [`INNER JOIN` can simulate with `INTERSECT` when used with `DISTINCT`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/03/sql-server-2005-difference-between-intersect-and-inner-join-intersect-vs-inner-join/). Thus, I think `INNER JOIN` would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, SQLite implements `INTERSECT` by copying the results of the two queries into two temporary sorted tables, and then looking up each `Id` value of the first table in the second table.

An `INNER JOIN` is implemented as a nested loop join, i.e., each `Id` value of one table is looked up in the other table. (SQLite chooses the other table as the one with an index on `Id`; if neither table has such an index, it creates a temporary index.)

So the pratical difference is that `INTERSECT` always creates temporary tables, while `JOIN` can work directly on the actual tables.
(If `T1` and `T2` were complicated subqueries, `JOIN` would also need temporary tables, and there would be no difference.)